# how to rewrite this link

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have created a link like this for access full product when someone click on this link.
but its looks a horrible when its alive on the link bar.

my link like this

```
 <a href="ad-view-cproject.php?url=<?php echo $Link; ?>&tsm=<?php echo $Cat;?>">
```

so what i did is , i made this "ad-view-cproject.php" to "ad" in my .htaccess file .

now my link looks like this

```
<a href="ad?url=<?php echo $Link; ?>&tsm=<?php echo $Cat;?>">
```

but when its come live on link bar its like this

> http://localhost/cproject/ad?url=J46TKlqSw3Gt4sk&tsm=Education

what i want to do is to replace this url in a url like this .

> http://localhost/cproject/ad/J46TKlqSw3Gt4sk-Education

I want to get rid of = marks and question marks.

Is this posible to do  ?

Comment: I think this is something for url rewriting.

Comment: yes this is what i want to know

Comment: something like: `RewriteRule ^ad/(.*)-(.*)$ ad-view-cproject.php?url=$1&tsm=$2 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.htacces`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^ad/([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z]+)$ index.php?url=$1&tsm=$2 [QSA,L]
```

regular expression how `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` help you execute wrong symboles

Comment: how can i put this in my script ?

Comment: @LeoneMaleash you should create file .htaccess in your root directory near index.php

Comment: at the moment i have created htaccess and i knowhow to put this on that. What i want  to know is, How to write the url in my script i mean my web page .
my url looks like this 
cproject/ad?url=J46TKlqSw3Gt4sk&tsm=Education

can i replace it  like this ? 

cproject/ad/url/J46TKlqSw3Gt4sk&tsm/Education

Comment: If you have link `cproject/ad?url=J46TKlqSw3Gt4sk&tsm=Education` you have not `index.php` only `ad.php`, in directory `cproject`. Then your `.htaccess` should be near ad.php and you will have line `RewriteRule ^ad/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z]+)$ ad.php?url=$1&tsm=$2 [QSA,L]` and url will `cproject/ad/J46TKlqSw3Gt4sk/Education`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you .htaccess

`RewriteRule ^ad/([\w]+)-([\w]+) ad-view-cproject.php?url=$1&tsm=$2`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this rewrite rule

`RewriteRule ^ad\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)  /ad?url=$1&tsm=$2`

You should also define a regex ruleset for the "code"

Comment: can  you please tell me how to write my url in my script ?

Comment: this code goes in `.htaccess` of your website root dir, the URL rewriting is done by the WebServer, not by the PHP Script

Comment: you can check at [official docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) for more info

Comment: im using your script. but it dosnt let me get the  value of the url.When im using $_GET['ad']; function

Comment: `ad` is the page requested that goes into the rewrite rule. You will get the `$_GET['url']` and `$_GET['tsm']` parameters, try making a `var_dump($_GET)`